# VBScript msgbox with NL

Tags: vbscript

I have the following code that displays a `MsgBox` using two env variables:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Title = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Title%")
Text = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Text%")
x = MsgBox(Text, 4144, Title)
```

Whilst the code works I wish t have a new line character in the message. I have read the following which discusses this scenario:
[How to use \n new line in VB msgbox() ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152042/how-to-use-n-new-line-in-vb-msgbox)

However when I sen the env variable to the following it is displayed literally.

```
"This is the first line" & vbCrLf & "and this is the second line"
```

Just in case the code above is unclear...

The env variables `%Title%` and `%Text%` are set with values like in these batch statements:

```
set Title="This is a title"
set Text="This is the first line" & vbCrLf & "and this is the second line"
```

The code reads and displays these env variables in a message box.

Comment: This is it. Is it working for you showing two lines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pop up Message in batch cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272110/pop-up-message-in-batch-cmd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expanded environment string is still a string, so VBScript doesn't evaluate it as VBScript code without you telling it to do so.

```
x = MsgBox(Eval(Text), 4144, Eval(Title))
```

However, [`Eval`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/11/01/eval-is-evil-part-one/) [is](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/11/04/eval-is-evil-part-two/) [evil](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/01/26/eval-is-evil-part-three/) and should be avoided.

A better approach would be to define your environment variables using a placeholder for the newlines (e.g. `\n`) and then replace the placeholders with actual newlines:

```
x = MsgBox(Replace(Text, "\n", vbNewLine), 4144, Replace(Title, "\n", vbNewLine))
```

Comment: Grr, you beat me to it :)

Comment: *\*blows smoke from gun muzzle\**

Comment: [Been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21272344/692942) in various forms.